# Why does plt.show () not show pictures on screen

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, object-detection

plt.show() doesn't work. I want to see the picture I made the object recognition but it does not appear on the screen

I'm new on this because I couldn't try anything something before, I want to try something I'm investigating

```
 for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
  image = Image.open(image_path)

  image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)

  image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)  

  output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
  image_np,
  output_dict['detection_boxes'],
  output_dict['detection_classes'],
  output_dict['detection_scores'],
  category_index,
  instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
  use_normalized_coordinates=True,
  line_thickness=8)

 plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
 plt.imshow(image_np)
 plt.show()
```

the program seems to be running smoothly but the screen does not show the image
inactive code in the last row, please help me

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you try to reduce your example and remove the `vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array` command to see whether it is actually `plt.show()` that does not work ?

Comment: vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array I have deleted the lines that are included in this command and operating function again, but did not print the image on the screen

Comment: when I run in two ways I get such a printout 
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Try running code in Terminal.

Comment: how can i do, i am amateur sorry

Comment: Your problem may be due to your working environment rather than your program itself. Are you working with pycharm under win10 ?

Comment: Yes i have win 10